# Cassandra new datacenter: do I need to 'repair'

Tags: cassandra

I'm setting up a new datacenter and I did `alter keyspace` to change the replication factor for that datacenter.

Do I need to run `nodetool repair` on the existing nodes?

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted; the procedure required for bringing up a whole new DC vs. just adding a new node to an existing DC *is* different.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding a new datacenter, then you actually need to run `nodetool rebuild`.  You would only run `nodetool repair` if you were adding a new node to an existing data center.

From the doc [Adding a data center to a cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_dc_to_cluster_t.html):

> After all nodes are running in the cluster:
>   Change the keyspace properties to specify the desired replication
>   factor for the new data center. For example, set strategy options to
>   DC1:2, DC2:2.
>
> For more information, see ALTER KEYSPACE.
>
> Run nodetool rebuild specifying the existing data center on all nodes
>   in the new data center: `nodetool rebuild -- name_of_existing_data_center`

Note that for this command to work, you must be on the node which you are rebuilding.  Otherwise, specify its IP/hostname with the command (as you would any other `nodetool` command).

Comment: @CedricH. Glad to help.  We were just bringing up some new cloud-based DCs, so I had to do this myself about 7 hours before you asked your question.  Perfect timing!